# What was this game with different symbols on puzzle pieces

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to identify this game from memory. When I was a kid, me and some extended family members would often play this game at an elderly neighbor’s house. I remember always wanting to play the game, and she (the neighbor) stored in in a brown paper bag. The details I remember of it are a little fuzzy, so apologies if I can’t remember all the rules or how the game is played exactly. And the elderly neighbor passed away over a decade ago, so I can’t ask her.

- Each of the players would grab a starting puzzle piece. There was a pool of pieces, that looked like puzzle pieces. The pieces would fit based on matching symbols.
- Each player would try to take pieces from the pool or give pieces back.
- The point of the game I think was to either create the longest sequence of symbols. Or it was to get the entire puzzle surrounded by one symbol. Or it was to get the longest puzzle.
- If I had to guess on the colors of the pieces, my memory says they were navy blue and silver.

Any idea on what the game is?

Comment: I appreciate your memory is fuzzy but a few more details might help.  my 'puzzle piece' do you mean shaped like a jigsaw piece?  How big do you think they were? The 'pool of pieces' were tiles face up or down?   When you said 'would try to take pieces from pool of give back?'  Do you remember any more about how?  That sounds like where the game rule is and might help prompt a memory in someone.